# Is there any automated way to update and manage Java/Scala dependencies with Gradle?

Tags: java, scala, gradle, dependency-management

I've recently returned to working on a Scala project, after having spent some time working with the nodejs ecosystem. After getting used to package managers like `npm` and `yarn`, I feel like I need to rethink the tools/processes I've been using for Java/Scala. With that in mind, there are several problems which appear to exist in the JVM world for which I'd like to know if there's some automated solution:

1. Given some list of dependencies without versions (but with group, module), is there some automated way to detect what the valid combinations (if any exist) of versions for each dependency are? Specifically, ensuring that there are no conflicting transitive dependencies?
   I believe Java Modules should reduce/eliminate this issue, but I'm currently limited to Java 8 so can't use them.
2. Aside from manually changing version numbers in my `build.gradle`, is there any automated way to update a dependency from cli?
   For example, I can do `yarn install <package>@<version>` to record the new version of a nodejs library I depend on *and install it* in one step - does anything similar exist for JVM projects?
3. Are there any tools similar to [updtr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/updtr) for Java/Scala projects? Basically; a tool that will automatically try to update my dependencies and run tests with the new versions, and rollback if anything fails.

---

In case it matters, I'm currently using gradle as my build tool in a Scala 2.11 project; but I'm curious to know about any answers that would apply to any mixed language project using any build tool. Ultimately I just want to avoid manually checking every one of my dependencies against every other dependency manually - anything else is an extra nicety.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer only point **3** of your question, and even this - only partially.

You might be interested in [Gradle Versions Plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) by [Ben Manes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19450/ben-manes).

This plugin does *not* update your dependencies (so all the more it does *not* have the test-running + rollback functionality).

However, it will list all the dependencies that can be upgraded, like that (it's only one of the possible formats):

> ```
> The following dependencies are using the latest integration
> version:
>  - backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1
>  - backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent-java12:3.1
>
> The following dependencies exceed the version found at the integration
> revision level:
>  - com.google.guava:guava [99.0-SNAPSHOT  3.0]
>      http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/
>  - com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings [2.0 -> 3.0]
>      http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/
>
> Gradle updates:
>  - Gradle: [4.6 -> 4.7 -> 4.8-rc-2]
> ```
>
> Source: [Report format](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin#report-format)

Moreover, the plugin can be configured as to what is *not* considered to be an upgradeable version:

> ```
> boolean rejected = ['alpha', 'beta', 'rc', 'cr', 'm'].any { qualifier ->
>   selection.candidate.version ==~ /(?i).*[.-]${qualifier}[.\d-]*/
> }
> ```
>
> Source: [Revisions](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin#revisions)

Comment: This looks great, thanks! Do you know how this will report dependency updates which have conflicting dependencies themselves? For example, `A v1.1` depends on `B v1.1`, `A v1.2` (latest) depends on `B v1.2`, `C v1.1` (latest) depends on `B v1.1` - the latest versions that I can safely use here are `A v1.1`, `B v1.1`, `C v1.1`: will this plugin support that? I couldn't find any information about this in the git repo.

Comment: I understand what you mean - you want maximum caution in dependency resolution, while Gradle's default policy is to be less cautious and just pick the highest version, which usually works (meaning `C v1.1` would use `B v1.2` as its dependency in such case). I don't think this plugin has the feature you're asking about, but Gradle itself can be configured e.g. to [fail on conflicts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting_dependency_resolution.html#sub:version_conflicts). Hope it helps, although we're getting even farther from your requested automation ;)